# Groovy iterate over Map of maps

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy map which looks like below.

```
image_map = [:]
image_map = [obj_1: ['1','2'], obj_2: ['3','4']]
```

I want to iterate through all the values(for obj_1, iterate throuth the list values['1','2']) for each object and run a method from the object.

```
obj_1.method(1)
obj_1.method(2)
obj_2.method(3)
obj_2.method(4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends why you want to do it, but you could grab the values and flatten them:

```
image_map.values().flatten().each {
    println it
}
```

So with the added requirement in the comment, you could do:

```
image_map.collectMany { k, v -> v.collect { "${k}.method($it)" } }
    .each { println it }
```

To print

```
obj_1.method(1)
obj_1.method(2)
obj_2.method(3)
obj_2.method(4)
```

Edit 2 with another requirement...  Assuming the keys ARE the objects (and not strings):

```
def obj_1 = [method: { it -> "I am obj1 $it" }]
def obj_2 = [method: { it -> "I am obj2 $it" }]

image_map = [(obj_1): ['1','2'], (obj_2): ['3','4']]

image_map.collectMany { k, v -> v.collect { [object: k, param: it] } }
    .each { println it.object.method(it.param) }
```

Prints:

```
I am obj1 1
I am obj1 2
I am obj2 3
I am obj2 4
```

Comment: obj_1 is an object. If i want to output both the object and the value in each iteration how can I do it? In one iteration i would like to get like this. `obj_1.method(1)` In the next iteration, I would like to get like `obj_1.method(2)`

Comment: Updated the answer 

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I actually wanted to execute .method from the obj_1 and obj_2 without printing it.

Comment: Updated again 